# What does 22/23 and 10.3/11.4 mean and why cannot access internet?

Tags: vlan, ip, vpn, internet

What does this specification mean? I asked the one who gave me this but I did not understand.

Vlan 22/23    192.168.10.3/11.4

a) Does 22/23 mean that 23 subnets have been allocated

b) The forward slash in 10.3/11.4 has something to do with CIDR or does it mean that 192.168.10.3 has been 
mapped to 192.168.11.4?

c) When using VPN to connect to 192.168.10.3 I can access internet but on 192.168.11.4 I do not.

Comment: Your question needs more context. Please add details like a network diagram or detail explanation of how the network devices are connected, the network device models, and the network device configurations. Without more information, we can only speculate or guess, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I undestand it as:

- VLAN 22 - 192.168.10.3
- VLAN 23 - 192.168.11.4

I.E. the IP address 192.168.10.3 is in VLAN 22 and the IP address 192.168.11.4 is in VLAN 23.

Regarding the VPN we cannot tell you what happens without knowing much more details about the network, the configuration of the VPN gateway, etc...